# How to install and use po2json?

Tags: json, wordpress, po

I want convert some wordpress `.po` language files to `.json` format and used wp-cli but PO files converted to multi files of json but I need to a single json file.

So installed po2json using:

```
npm install po2json
```

I am getting this error:

```
C:\Users\Mehdi\Desktop\po2json 1.0.0>po2json translation.po translation.json
'po2json' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Can anybody help me to use po2json easily?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tried to install https://openbase.com/js/@myrotvorets/po2json using:

```
npm i @myrotvorets/po2json
```

And finally I got the output with the following code:

```
po2json sourcefile.po > destfile.json
```